# Controlling a 20x20 single-color LED matrix

Tags: arduino, led, esp32, matrix

I want to control a white 20x20 LED Matrix with an Arduino or an ESP32, but I can't find a proper way to solve the problem that there are not enough pins on either of the two boards. I want to be able to control the brightness of each led individually, so I can't use a shift register. What other methods could I use? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong using shift registers, but you must update them fast enough to produce a PWM like dimming. Updating 400 bit with 100 Hz isn't a problem for an Arduino.

Comment: Which LED matrix? I assume all 400 LEDs are not individually exposed, but it's rather a 20 row + 20 column matrix?

Comment: Oh, 400 LEDs in total?  I had not had my coffee yet when I read this the 1st time.  In that case I would suggest you should look into how a HUB75 LED display board works.  Which is essentially what you hinted at in your question and what @Jens 's comment drives home.  Let me know if that appeals to you and I'll change my answer below from Charlie Plexing to HUB75.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a technique called [Charlie Plexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing) named after Charles "Charlie" M. Allen (also known as tristate multiplexing, reduced pin-count LED multiplexing, complementary LED drive and crossplexing).

[This Instructables posting](https://www.instructables.com/Controlling-20-Leds-from-5-Arduino-pins-using-Cha/) controls 20 LED from 5 Arduino pins.

[image]

In normal Charlie Plexing, each LED is lit individually. Most Charlieplexing applications only light 1 or a few LEDs at a time.  In reality, unless care is taken with the hardware and software, only 1 LED is actually lit at any given time. For example, [this Charlieplexing watch](https://github.com/osresearch/charliewatch) normally only lights a minute and hour LED at any given moment. To very the brightness, drive the LED with [Pulse Width Modulation (PWM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) to control the brightness.

Comment: This will lead to horribly low brightness when driving a 20 x 20 matrix since you can only turn on one at a time instead of a whole column. Also, this is unlikely to work with a row+column _matrix_ of LEDs.

Comment: I will change the answer to fit the situation @pipe.